# react useState array displays undefined

Tags: arrays, reactjs, api

I am build an app using react and api from Moviesdb. I get results from the api but if I want to access individual value of the json data i get fron the api I shows Movies[0] is undefined error

```
const [Movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`${MOVIE_API_URL}movie/popular?api_key=${MOVIE_API_KEY}&lang=en-us&page=1`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            setMovies(response.results)
        });
}, []);
return (
    <div style={{ width: '100%', margin: 0 }} >

        <MainImage
            Image={`${MOVIE_IMAGE_URL}w1200${Movies[0].backdrop_path}`}
            title={Movies[0].original_title}
            text={Movies[0].overview}
        />
)
```

Movies displays this array below

```
[{
   adult: false
   backdrop_path: "/5BwqwxMEjeFtdknRV792Svo0K1v.jpg"
   genre_ids: Array [ 18, 878 ]
   id: 419704
}
{
   adult: false
   backdrop_path: "/1R6cvRtZgsYCkh8UFuWFN33xBP4.jpg"​​
   genre_ids: Array(3) [ 28, 18, 53 ]​       id: 545609
}]
```

but Movies[0].backdrop_path show Movies[0] is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely that rendering starts earlier than the response comes from the server, try adding a check to an empty array

```
{ Movies.length &&
      <MainImage
            Image={`${MOVIE_IMAGE_URL}w1200${Movies[0].backdrop_path}`}
            title={Movies[0].original_title}
            text={Movies[0].overview}
        />
}
```